# Get io_context reference from a socket in Boost 1.73+ Asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

How can I get `boost::asio::io_context` reference from a socket? Previously there were `socket::get_io_service` and then `socket::get_io_context` member functions, however now they both are deprecated. I've found the only way to do this in Boost 1.73+:

```cpp
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(...);
// ...
boost::asio::io_context& io_context = static_cast<boost::asio::io_context&>(socket.get_executor().context());
```

This works, however looks ugly and dangerous. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would probably want to get the executor, which might be something other than the io_context.

There's a `get_executor()` call to do it directly:

```
boost::asio::io_context io;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket s(io);
auto ex = s.get_executor();
```

The executor will allow you to do most things you were probably using the `io_context` for.

### UPDATE

To the comment, I do NOT recommend relying on the exact target of the executor you get passed in via any service object, but you can force your hand if you really don't want to update your design right now:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ac33ff04c37d88b)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket s(io);

    auto ex = s.get_executor();

    auto* c = ex.target<boost::asio::io_context>();
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket more_sockets(*c);

    assert(c == &io);
}
```

When compositing async operations, you can derive an executor from a handler using `boost::asio::get_associated_executor()`

Comment: No, I need io_context, not executor. I need io_context reference to construct another socket, or a strand, or an acceptor, or whatever else that constructs from io_context reference.

Comment: Sorry if this discussion is starting to go beyond the original question :) I can construct socket, acceptor and resolver from the executor - OK, that's fine. However strand instance still requires io_context reference on construction, not the executor. I'll accept your answer, but could you please explain what should I do with strands - I don't want to pass references to socket AND io_context since its kinda superfluously - a socket already "know" its io_context. And why relying on the executor underlying io_context reference is a bad design?

Comment: I guess the logical concept here is: you _should_ not be dynamically instantiating these objects in some "assumed" context. Especially strands: it seem to be a design smell to dynamically spin off strands. For composed operations, you would use the `get_associated_executor` to have your intermediate handlers run on the strand associated with the handler you are composing.  I think if you do that "for a living" then `boost::asio::async_compose` is there to make your life easier (I should still learn more about that).

Comment: For now, I would perhaps use `make_strand(sock.get_excutor())` which looks like it very much results in the _same strand identity_: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebea5bd0d55994ec